# Variables export in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i am trying to export a varibles like this

```
const test1 = [
{numbder:'one', name:'user',tag: 'test'}
]
const test2 = [
{numbder:'one', name:'user',tag: 'test'}
]
module.exports = { test1, test2 }
```

and i import it like this

```
const test = require('./test.js')

myfunction function () {
 console.log(test1 +'and'+ test2)
}
```

I get this error :

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'test1' before initialization
```

could anyone explaine to me what is the problem?

Comment: You probably wanted to write: `test.test1` instead of just `test1`

Comment: That's because `test === { test1, test2 }`. `test` is defined, `test1` is not.

Comment: clearly this is not code you testing, since `myfunction function ()` will cause an error before the code even runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [destruct](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment) the values from `test`.

```
const { test1, test2 } = require('./test.js')

function myfunction() {
 console.log(test1 +'and'+ test2)
}
```

another solution:

```
const test = require('./test.js')

function myfunction() {
 console.log(test.test1 +'and'+ test.test2)
}
```

Comment: is there also other way to import it, i tried both of solution and still get error thanks alot for your answer

Comment: no, that's how you do it correctly - your actual code must be wrong

Comment: "Still get error" which error? I'm getting `unexpected token 'function'`. What is wrong is `myfunction function ()` instead of `function myfunction ()`

Comment: @JeremyThille -  It's supposed to be `function myfunction() {...}`, not `myfunction function() {...}`.  And, `console.log(test1 +'and'+ test2)` will not do anything useful either once you get rid of the errors on `test1` and `test2`.

Comment: And of course, `myfunction` remains a mystery (in the original question of course).

Comment: Just work by changing the `module.exporest` at the end of the code, i was put it at the top

Comment: it should be: `function myfunction() { }` or `var myfunction = function() {}`